# Do word boundaries work on symbol characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I'm trying to implement word boundaries in my emoticons feature for a chat. But for some reason I can't seem to get the word boundaries to work. I am new to regex.

So when I do:

```
var reg = /\b\Hi\b/gi;
var str = 'HiHiHi Hi HiHiHi Hi';
alert(str.replace(reg, ''));
```

This happens: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ESb8n/)

It actually works fine, and does remove those 2 Hi's that are standing alone.

But when I change the reg to an escaped smiley and then change the string:

```
var reg = /\b\:\)\b/gi;
var str = 'HiHi:) :) HiHiHi :)';
alert(str.replace(reg, ''));
```

This happens:
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzqu8/)

It just doesn't work. The string stays the same. Is it that word boundaries can't be used on symbols? If so, how does Facebook do it on their chats?

Comment: Please add some examples of what you **do** and **don't** want to match.

Comment: What do you mean by "How does Facebook do it...?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `\b` will not work in this case, you could use:

```
var re = /(\s|^):\)(?!\S)/g;
var str = 'HiHi:) :) HiHiHi :)';
alert(str.replace(re, '$1'));
```

Which works like a space boundary.

You can add several smileys to it like so:

```
/(\s|^)(?::\)|:\(|:\||:\]|:\[)(?!\S)/g;
```

Comment: @Shawn31313, see update. Don't forget to escape the meta characters.

Comment: Ok. Now how would I add that reg above in the new RegExp() javascript object?

Comment: @Shawn31313, fix the syntax errors, and double escape the backslashes when quoting: http://jsfiddle.net/Bzqu8/5/

Comment: Yes, haha just realized that so I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Word boundaries `\b` represent a zero-width boundary between word characters `\w` (in javascript, `[A-Za-z_]`) and non-word characters `\W` (everything else).

Because of this, there will not be a boundary between two emoticons or when the emoticon is surrounded by spaces, punctuation, etc.

The simplest regex would be `/[:;]-?[()]/gi`, which supports smileys `)` and frownies `(` with optional dashes and eyes `:` or winks `;`.

**Edit:**

This will require either a space or the beginning of the string (as a capturing group since Javascript doesn't support look-behinds), then it uses the above regex, then it must be followed by the end of string or whitespace.

```
var reg = /(\s|^)[:;]-?[()](?:\s|$)/gi;
var str = 'HiHi:) :) HiHiHi :)';
alert(str.replace(reg, '$1'));
```

Should replace in these situations: `:-)`, `cool :( not!`

Should not replace in these situations: `Digits:(0,1,2,3)`, `hi :(.`

Comment: Or more simply: `\w` and `\W`. While Javascript uses only ASCII, in general many regex engines have much larger classes for `\w`.

Comment: So there is no way I can use word boundaries for this :/

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  You might try `\B` to see if that improves things for you, but i don't think it will.  Please add some examples of what you **don't** want to match.

Comment: I only want it to match standing alone smileys for example when someone is a chat write: "Hi:)" the ":)" wont turn into a smiley in this case. But it should if you have: "Hi :)"