# how to match non-word+word boundary in javascript regex

Tags: regex

how to match non-word+word boundary in javascript regex.

```
"This is, a beautiful island".match(/\bis,\b/)
```

In the above case why does not the regex engine match till is, and assume the space to be a word boundary without moving further.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10983983/3832970 and especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` asserts a position where a word character `\w` meets a non-word character `\W` or vice versa. Comma is a non-word character and space is as well. So `\b` never matches a position between a comma and a space.

Also you forgot to put ending delimiter in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\B` after comma that matches where `\b` doesn't since comma is not considered a word character.

```js
console.log( "This is, a beautiful island".match(/\bis,\B/) )
//=> ["is,"]
```